# Changing cell padding for a specific row in CSS

Tags: html, css

I need to change the cell padding between the logos in the first row of the below table

[image]

I select the DOM element from Div as follows (Changed the Div class for Australia as "tableLogoAus")

When I set the margin as below it messed up the whole row

```
 div#tableLogoAus table td{
    
 margin: 0px -10px 0px 0px;
  }
```

HTML code is below

```
<p class="trigger"><u class="bnplChart">See All Buy Now Pay Later Options</u></p>
         <div class="modal">
          <div class="modalbnpl-content">
            
              <span class="close-button">&times;</span>
              
                <table class="size-info-bnpltable">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                <th scope="col" class="bnpltableHead">Country</th>
                <th scope="col" class="bnpltableHead">Available BNPL options</th>
                
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  
                <tr>
                
                   <td class="bnpltableHead">Australia</td>
                  
                
                <td>
                  **<div class="tableLogoAus">**  
                  <img class="afterpay" src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1084/7742/files/afterpay1.png?v=1679358773"> 
                  <img class="zippay" src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1084/7742/files/zip1.png?v=1679358773"> <img class="laybuy" src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1084/7742/files/logo-laybuy.png?v=1575868533">  <img class="klarna" src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1084/7742/files/klarna.png?v=1679358773">
                </div>
                  </td>
                
                  
               
                </tr>
                  
                <tr>
                <td class="bnpltableHead">United States</td>
                  
                 <td>
                  <div class="tableLogo">  
                  <img class="afterpay" src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1084/7742/files/afterpay1.png?v=1679358773">
                  <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1084/7742/files/sez_6b34600a-46d8-4dce-afbf-4ba445aadca4.jpg?v=1596434632"> 
                </div>
                  </td>
                
                
                </tr>
                  
                <tr>
                <td class="bnpltableHead">New Zealand</td>
                  
                <td>
                  <div class="tableLogo">  
                  <img class="afterpay" src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1084/7742/files/afterpay1.png?v=1679358773">
                  <img class="laybuy" src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1084/7742/files/logo-laybuy.png?v=1575868533"> 
                </div>
                  </td>
               
                </tr>
                  <tr>
                <td class="bnpltableHead">Canada</td>
                    
                <td>
                  <div class="tableLogo">  
                  <img class="afterpay" src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1084/7742/files/afterpay1.png?v=1679358773">
                  <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1084/7742/files/sez_6b34600a-46d8-4dce-afbf-4ba445aadca4.jpg?v=1596434632"> 
                </div>
                  </td>
                
                </tr>
                  <tr>
                <td class="bnpltableHead">United Kingdom</td>
                    
                <td>
                  <div class="tableLogo">  
                  <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1084/7742/files/clearpay1.png?v=1679358773">
                  <img class="laybuy" src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1084/7742/files/logo-laybuy.png?v=1575868533"> 
                </div>
                  </td>
                
                </tr>
                   <tr>
                <td class="bnpltableHead">France</td>
                    
                <td>
                  <div class="tableLogo">  
                  <img class="afterpay" src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1084/7742/files/afterpay1.png?v=1679358773">
                </div>
                  </td>
                
                </tr>
                </tbody>
                </table>
                <p>If you are checking out in USD, CAD, GBP or NZD and wish to pay using one of our Buy Now, Pay Later options; you must select AUD from the currency selector located on the bottom left of website before the checkout page.</p>
         <p>If you do not change the currency to AUD; you will not be able to view the BNPL payment options.</p>
          </div>
      </div>
         </div>
    <style>
.size-info-bnpltable{
    width: auto !important;
  }

  .tableLogo{
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content:left;
    align-items:left;
  }
  div#tableLogoAus table td{
    
 margin: 0px -10px 0px 0px;
  }
  
  .tableLogo img{
    height:30px;
    width:auto;
    margin: 2px 5px;
  }

   img.laybuy{
    height:20px;
     
  }
</style>
```

Any suggestions how to have equal margin between the logos only for the first row?

Answer (score 0):

I dont understand why you use

```
    
 margin: 0px -10px 0px 0px;
  }
```

while logo elements inside tableLogoAus class is image tag.

Btw, you can use this code to solve your problem:

```
.tableLogoAus img {
    padding: 20px;
}
```